# PHP functions nested foreach loop does not work

Tags: php

Why doesn't this code work when i call it via function? It only works for the outer loop but the inner loop does not return values?

```
<?php populateEnrollment($products); ?>

<?php
function populateEnrollment($value){

    foreach($value as $productid => $prod) if ($productid ==101)
    { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width=300 class="tah11">'. $prod["name"] .'</td>' ;
        echo '<td width=100 class="tah11"><div align="center"> <select name="enrollName"id="enrollNameId" >';
            foreach ($prod["membershipType"] as $type)
            {
                echo '<option value="' .$type["price"]; $typeIdPrice = $typeId["price"] .'">'.$type["name"] . ' at $' . $typeIdPrice . '</option>';
                echo '</select>';
                echo '</td>';                               
            } // end of foreach membershipTypen
    } // end of products foreach
} // end of function populateEnrollment
?>
```

Comment: Try `print_r($prod["membershipType"]);` to check whether it contains anything

Comment: Functions are mainly used for repetitive codes, I don't think this code is repetitive so why use a function?

Comment: Have you debug anything so far ? Check your output for `print_r($prod["membershipType"]);` before starting inner loop.

Comment: `echo '<option value="' .$type["price"]; $typeIdPrice = $typeId["price"] .'">'.$type["name"] . ' at $' . $typeIdPrice . '</option>';` this line is problematic. your <option> tag will never be closed like this.

Comment: when you use a flow control without proper curly braces you're gonna have a bad time. Also, a kitten, a puppy and a bunny die horribly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add echo `</select></td>` out side your inner foreach loop.

Also the way you are echoing `<option>` is also wrong please check here

Changed $typeId to $type .. minor typo update

```
<?php
function populateEnrollment($value){

    foreach($value as $productid => $prod) if ($productid ==101){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width=300 class="tah11">'. $prod["name"] .'</td>' ;
    echo '<td width=100 class="tah11"><div align="center"> <select name="enrollName"id="enrollNameId" >';
    foreach ($prod["membershipType"] as $type){
           echo '<option value="' .$type["price"] .'">'.$type["name"] . ' at $' . $type["price"] . '</option>';

    } // end of foreach membershipTypen

    echo '</select>';
    echo '</td>';                               

    } // end of products foreach
} // end of function populateEnrollment
?>
```

Comment: Is this a answer ? Can you add your explanation if you have change or corrected anything in code posted by OP.

Comment: @Rikesh Too hurry! I am doing that. :P

Comment: This worked ... so the reason why it did not work was because I was not echoing <option> properly ... Thanks a bunch .. I am new to PHP and I totally missed that!

Comment: @user3122466 On left side of my answer you can see tick option.

Comment: I have a follow up question, should I ask it here or add a new question?

It is related to updating a textbox with the value the user selects from the dropdown without refreshing the page or using the $GET

Comment: @user3122466 If its not related to this then ask new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
<?php populateEnrollment($products); ?>

function populateEnrollment($value)
{

    foreach($value as $productid => $prod) 
    { 
        if ($productid ==101)
        {
            ?><tr><?php
            ?><td width=300 class="tah11"><?=$prod["name"]?></td><?php
            ?><td width=100 class="tah11"><div align="center">
                <select name="enrollName"id="enrollNameId" >
                <?php
                foreach ($prod["membershipType"] as $type)
                {
                    echo '<option value="' .$type["price"]; $typeIdPrice = $typeId["price"] .'">'.$type["name"] . ' at $' . $typeIdPrice . '</option>';
                }
            ?></td><?php
            ?></tr><?php
        }
    }
}
```